# Understanding garbage collector in java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm trying to understand the Concurrent mark and sweep GC algorithm. I'm reading the following [***explanation***](https://plumbr.eu/handbook/garbage-collection-algorithms#sweep):
[image]

***QUESTION:*** So what does the sweep actually mean? Is it the actual garbage collection (reclaiming unreachable object and freeing memory?)? Or it means something different?

If so, what kind of troubles we can run into if we ***omit the sweep phase***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the linked explanation the "sweep" step is actually not described.

Roughly speeking:

1. **mark**: find the "root" object(s), and perform a traversal of the object graph, *marking* all objects, which are touched during the traversal.
2. **sweep**: go through your heap from A to Z and delete all objects which aren't marked (*sweep* through your heap; or *sweep* the non-marked objects from your heap).

If you don't do sweep the memory is not freed, just marked as free (think of the "Trash bin" in your OS -> mark = put into trash bin; sweep = delete from trash bin).

Comment: Ah... Understood. This is the not the stop-the-world phase, right?

Comment: But we can allocate a new object in the memory region which is marked as free?

Comment: @St.Antario: stop-the-world: that's another question, which has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40200257/5471574

Comment: @St.Antario: no, the memory is not freed yet, the JVM will not allocate objects there.

Comment: @StAntario: in order to allocate a new object in that memory region, you need to know the address of the free region. Finding that address (and linking all of them) is exactly what sweeping is about.

Comment: @Holger So sweeping can be threated something like `free()` in C?

Comment: @St.Antario: essentially it will be `free()` and other stuff in a loop what the JVM does behind the curtains, yes

Comment: @StAntario: you can see it that way, but usually, sweeping implies making the memory available for new allocations within the JVM, whereas `free()` is often associated with giving the memory back to the operating system.